# Flexible array as a class member

Tags: c++, flexible-array-member

GCC G++ 9

This code:

```
   class foo {
     int bar[] = {111, 123};
   };
```

produces an error about initializer for flexible array. But this one:

```
   class foo {
     int bar[2] = {111, 123};
   };
```

compiles as normal. Any workaround for not counting the values I put in?

Comment: Hint: `std::vector`. C++ needs to know the exact size of a structure in advance. You can't make it up as you go.

Comment: No, no workarounds. C++ just doesn't work this way.

Comment: std::vector suits well for my usecase as i tested. it supports [] notation and does not want me to specify array size. i was aware of it, just i was not prepared that flexible array would be of a problem. thanks!!! :)

Comment: There is no such thing as flexible array member in C++

Comment: @Slava Doesn't `static constexpr int bar[] = {111, 123};` count as a flexible array member? It's probably unusable for OP, but still.

Comment: @tadman There is no boost library on an Arduino. Sometimes libraries can't replace missing language features.

Comment: @Martin This isn't Boost, it's in the C++ Standard Library. If that's not an option for *reasons* then that needs to be specified in the question as that's an edge case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike in a function where you can do

```
int foo[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

and the compiler will deduce the size of `foo` from the initializer, when you do

```
struct bar
{
    int foo[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
};
```

what you really have is

```
struct bar
{
    bar() : foo{ 1, 2, 3 } {}
    int foo[];
};
```

and that can't work because C++ does not allow flexible arrays like C does.

That leaves you with two options.  The first is you specify the size.  This isn't the greatest solution since it could introduce bugs but it will save you from dynamic initialization.  The second option is to use a type that, at run time, can be initialized from the list.  A `std::vector` for instance would fill that requirement nicely.  Yes, there will be a dynamic memory allocation, but since `std::vector` is an [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) type, you don't need to worry about it and can use the default constructors and destructor.

Comment: If a fixed size array is wanted, `std::array<int,2>` would be also appropriate.

Comment: @tohaz It's a great container.  It's my go-to unless I can use a `std::array`

Comment: For `std::array` (without having to count the values) I guess something like `static constexpr std::array init = {111, 123}; std::remove_const_t<decltype(init)> bar = init;` could be an option.

Comment: Of course all the `std::…` solutions won't help if the target device is an Arduino where there is no boost library. Sometimes libraries can't make up for lack of language functionality.